# Create a scheduled or Cron Job that runs at a specific time of day

Tags: java

I need to create a scheduled job or Cron job in Java to run every morning at 6am.
Is there a simple way to do it. I have tried to use Timer class with the scheduledAtFixedRate  method but it takes a only a delay.

There is a method that can take a day as first time and then period

How will you create a specific date and time to start the scheduler?

My Class that needs to run the job is already extended with TimerTask.

Answer (score 1):

When I listen something like "execute something at that precise time with Java", I am thinking about Timer or Quartz Scheduling. They have pro and cons, but you can use them safely.

You have an example of scheduled task inside [that Quart Official Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/quartz) :

```
package org.acme.quartz;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import io.quarkus.scheduler.Scheduled;

@ApplicationScoped 
public class TaskBean {

    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(every = "10s", identity = "task-job") 
    void schedule() {
        Task task = new Task(); 
        task.persist(); 
    }
}
```

Another way is this one, for the repeating period part :

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(60).repeatForever()).build();
```

Another way again, is the ability to use CronExpression :

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().startNow()
          .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(expression))
          .build();
```

Where expression is a [CRON expression](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html).

If you do not know Quartz, you can look at their [Cookbook](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/cookbook/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cron4j](https://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/). Or overload your method with signature `(delay)` with another one with signature `(date,delay)` that will get the current date, wait until the first occurrence and then call the already defined method with `(delay)` signature... aka using `schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)` of the class [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).